Flutter app resumes on the same page even after long periods of being minimized (days or months)
To restart the app after being minimized for a long time.this is main problem and
also shows one warning also, that is W/WindowOnBackDispatcher(26296): Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.so  when i set in the manifest.xml then the app swipe back not working properly ,which go to minimize.
